# Watchkit doesn't see Parse Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, cocoapods, watchkit

Previously implemented Parse by dragging and dropping files into my projects Frameworks folder.  Because I needed to utilize another 3rd party library, I installed this library using cocoapods (and must use the workspace now instead of xcode project).

Since I had a podfile now, apparently Xcode was looking to it instead of my Frameworks folder because it didn't recognize the library...so I deleted the frameworks from the project and installed Parse through cocoapods.

My main app looks fine now, however now my Watchkit Extension classes do not recognize the module Parse.

This is what my Watchkit Extension Linked Frameworks and Libs looks like... I don't understand the red?

[image]

I think the problem is that my search paths in my Build Settings of WatchKit Extension are pointing to the old Framework files instead of the new one....but I'm not sure where to set these search paths to point toward my Pods?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you click on the bolts / parse framework / cocoa pods that the target for watch kit extension is also ticked.

Comment: thanks but I'm not using cocoa pods...just dragged frameworks manually, but Watchkit is seeing Parse fine... again I can query 1 level deep and return, just not 2...